# Spring MVC Deploying to more than one context path?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a built Spring MVC app called myapp.war

I'd like to deploy the single war to Tomcat 7 and have it assume the contexts of /myapp and / (root)

Is this possible via configuration?

thanks -

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be accomplished via Tomcat configuration, but you could also just deploy your application to `ROOT` with a Controller that will map requests to both `http://my-server/myapp/` and `http://my-server/`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/myapp"})
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String home() { return "home"; }

}
```

This example would map both `http://my-server/myapp/` and `http://my-server/` to your home page.

Comment: That will only map `http://my-server/myapp/`  and `http://my-server/myapp/myapp` to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your **server.xml**

```
<Context path="" docBase="myapp" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

For more info refer [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)